# How to create Account Child... Company, Staff Signup

Tags: php, database, customer-account, html

How do i create and attach a new set of field to a registered account?

I need a way to create company accounts and add the company's staff under said account. this way the company can see what each staff has purchased from us.

here's how it would work... we would register a company using Magentos account registration. the system we are trying to develop would then allow us to add employees to the registered company and generate an ID number for each. Each employee will receive their ID# and present it when purchasing goods or services. All goods and services purchased by an employee, will show up under his/her ID# in the companies account. This lets the company (employer) know who purchased what, when it was purchased and the total.

Only the company will have access to see this info, btw.

this way we can sum up the total transactions made by the companies employee, for the company to pay at the end of each month.

I believe the way to go about this is to make employees a "child" of the employer (company account)

I am still consider myself an armature at this stuff. but once i put my mind to the test i always achieve whatever im set to develop. I just need some help with finding the best way of achieving this. Please provide me with solution ideas on how to achieve this. The more details you provide the better.

I would appreciate any help in developing this!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have in the past done something similar. The approach that was used was:

Create a customer account through the normal process of registering a customer.

Then when new members of the team sign up, you edit them and add to their account a parent ID.

Then create a custom module which allows you to create a new tab in the customer account (front end) which would pull orders from all of the customers accounts which have the current logged in customer id as the parent id.

Comment: Oh thats great :)... Would it be possible for you to locate and share the files with me, or give me a more detailed walk-through of how u did it. I would greatly appreciate it. You are the 1st person on the internet that i have found who acknowledge that this can be done.